# How to silent print in django application

Tags: javascript, django

I have an application on django, that need to print a bill in silent mode, without user confirmation. I searched in google and found a lot of results for "print with javascript in silent mode", but doesn't works to me. I changed the flags in chrome,created a flag in firefox, downloaded qz tray (but the free version show an alert every time i send data to printer). How can i print silently from any browser like an kiosk application?

Comment: You want to print something to the user's printer without asking their permission? Have a guess as to why you can't do that.

Comment: I know that for security reasons you can not access a user's device without their consent, but what I need is that after clicking on print, the browser does not present the print dialog, but simply prints.

Answer (score 1):

> downloaded qz tray (but the free version show an alert every time i send data to printer)

This is partially true.  With some effort, you can suppress the dialogs even with the free version.  The two options are:

1. Launch QZ Tray with a custom certificate (e.g. override.crt) and then setup message signing using that.

   `java -Xms512M -DtrustedRootCert=path/to/override.crt -jar qz-tray.jar`

   Note, `authcert.override=path/to/override.crt` can also be added to qz-tray.properties to achieve the same effect.
2. Recompile the software with your own certificate embedded into the software.  QZ Tray makes this pretty easy during the compilation process.

   `ant nsis -Dauthcert.use=path/to/override.crt`

Most online tutorials use one of these two methods.

Note, the message signing step requires some server-side logic in Django.  The sample python source code is available for download here: https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/assets/signing/sign-message.py

This needs to be combined with the message signing example inside sample.html to guarantee that each request to the printer originates from a trusted source (in this case, you).